# How to send email after updating a user?

Tags: python, django, updates, sendmail

I want when updating a user, he / she receives an email informing that an update has occurred in the user, I tried something like:

```
 @transaction.atomic
def update_student(request):

        try:
            student = request.user.student

        except Student.DoesNotExist:

            student = Student(user=request.user)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = StudentUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=student)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save
                subject = 'Usuario atualizado'
                from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                to_email = [student.email]
                update_message = 'Usuario ativado com sucesso'
                send_mail(subject,from_email=from_email,recipient_list=to_email,message=update_message,fail_silently=False)
                return redirect('student_list')
            else:
                form = StudentUpdateForm(instance=student)
                return render('student_list')
```

But without success :( (Email was not sending)

Any suggestion?

email settings/settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' 
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' 
EMAIL_PORT = 587 EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER ='youemail@gmail.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'youpassword'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

The sending of emails to this case is not working, however to reset password yes

Comment: What do you mean by "without success"? Was there an error? Did it succeed but not send an email?

Comment: Email was not sending

Comment: what is your [email backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#obtaining-an-instance-of-an-email-backend)

Comment: EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER ='youemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'youpassword''
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings.py file:

```
#GMAIL
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' # for gmail
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com' #your email
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*********' #your pass
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com' #your email
```

Control access to insecure applications en google.

Comment: EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' EMAIL_PORT = 587 EMAIL_USE_TLS = True EMAIL_HOST_USER ='youemail@gmail.com' EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'youpassword'' DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER